# Can ably.io (AMQP|MQTT) queue clients authenticate using tokens?

Tags: ably-realtime

I'd like to allow untrusted clients to subscribe to MQTT and AMQP queues on ably.io.

Can I use one of the token authentication schemes described in https://www.ably.io/documentation/core-features/authentication#token-authentication somehow, or do I have to set up a separate API key for each client?

If the latter, can API keys be provisioned dynamically?

I went through the docs & help desk articles, but couldn't find anything regarding this combination. Is this just a missing feature or generally a bad idea on my part?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: Token authentication can be used for authenticating all kinds of Ably clients. As an example, have a look at the MQTT docs on Ably's website and you'll find the [authentication section](https://www.ably.io/documentation/mqtt#token-auth) that explains how to implement [Token Auth](https://www.ably.io/documentation/mqtt#token-auth) with MQTT. As you just said, using Token Authentication is not only more secure but also gives you a way as an admin of the app to set up your own authentication server to carry out your custom authentication strategy.

Hope that helps!

P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate for [Ably Realtime](https://ably.io).